# How can I determine if an Oracle table has the ROWDEPENDENCIES option set?

Tags: oracle10g

I only have the basic Oracle tools available, i.e. SQL Plus, and I need to find out if a table was created with the ROWDEPENDENCIES option. It's a 10g database.

And, if it isn't set, can I use ALTER TABLE to set it, or do I have to drop and re-create the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT owner, table_name, dependencies FROM dba_tables;
```

This will return "ENABLED" or "DISABLED" for each table. If you don't have access to `dba_tables`, query `all_tables` instead.

[You cannot change this after the table has been created](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402), so you'll have to re-create the table to set it on.