# Recreate table with data and relations

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some **data**. This table has 1:N relation to some other tables and this other tables have also some 1: N relations.

I need to recreate the table with some changes.So far I've created a table with the same structure and copied data into it from the original table.My intention is to delete the original table and rename the new table to match the orginal name.

The problem is I cannot delete the original table because of the child records.

How to solve this problem ? Or is there any other way for this kind of task ?

Comment: You would need to either drop the FK constraints, or delete the child records first. What changes are you making to the table structure? Do you really need to create it as a new table?

Comment: Yes I need to create a table with rowdependencies.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you can't set them up with ALTER TABLE, so you're doing the right thing. In which case, you have no option but to drop the constraints, drop the original table, rename the new table and then re-enable the constraints. This is a bit of a pain, but its the only way.. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105368/how-can-i-determine-if-an-oracle-table-has-the-rowdependencies-option-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to drop the constraints from the child table with something like:

```
ALTER TABLE <your child table> DROP CONSTRAINT <your constraint>;
```

Look for the constraints on the child table pointing to the parent.

Then you should be able to drop your old parent table, rename, and re-add the constraints.